# Use DecimalFormat for output like "..11,22,33,777.99"

Tags: java, bigdecimal, decimalformat

I am trying to format a number using Java DecimalFormat. Can someone help on this to achieve expected formatting.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal("777777777.77");
    String fromatter = "#,##,##0.00";
    DecimalFormat formater = new DecimalFormat(fromatter);
    System.out.println(formater.format(decimal));

    //Expectation: 77,77,77,777.77
    //Actual: 77,7777,777.77
}
```

Comment: See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). If you supply a pattern with multiple grouping characters, the interval between the last one and the end of the integer is the one that is used. So "#,##,###,####" == "######,####" == "##,####,####".